# Non-singularity of a block anti-diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices

Let us suppose we have an $(2n)\times(2n)$ symmetric matrix with the block structure:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & B \\
        B^T & 0\\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

where every sub-block is of dimension $n\times n$. If every element of $B$ is non-zero can we infer that the matrix is non-singular. We can clearly see that the determinant of the matrix is $-\det(B^T B)$ Our hunch is that the matrix is non-singular although we cannot prove that $-\det(B^T B)$ is non-zero. Any ideas for a proof ?

Comment: "If every element of B is non-zero can we infer that the matrix is non-singular." Think about a matrix of ones.

Answer (score 2):

As $\det(B^TB)=\det(B)^2$, it follows that your block matrix is non-singular if and only if $B$ is non-singular.